# Is there any checklist to avoid crashes when using OpenCV SVM?

Tags: c++, opencv

I' stepping through SVM in OpenCV 2.4 slowly. From one crash to another
Is there any list of suggestions, how to check the data befode feeding it to train and predict functions?

Currently I have crashes when calling predict and can't figure out why.

This is the section of code which should be relevant:

```
            row = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 256, CV_32FC1); 
            for ( std::map<int, int>::iterator fit = tmp.begin(); fit != tmp.end(); fit ++ )
            {
                row.at<float>(0, fit->first) = fit->second;


            }               
            float result = svm.predict(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be another not documented stumbling block.
When I create the CvSVM - instance on the heap, it doesn't crash any more.

I used to create a global instance ov CvSVM in my test code, and assign to it actual data later:

```
CvSVM _svm;
//... some code and scopes
//training
_svm = CvSVM (trainingData, trainingClasses, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), param);
//... some code and scopes
//testing
float l = _svm.predict(testData)
```

It crashed in predict, because the labels mat vas not initialized